# Explain group by query

Tags: sql-server, group-by, aggregate

I'm very new to sql and database.
Came across this query:

```
  SELECT cast(min(dt_from) as varchar(12))+cast(max(dt_to) as varchar (12))
FROM view1
GROUP BY dt_from, dt_to
```

When I exclude the group by I get only one record but with group by I get 40,Can someone please explain the logic behind this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

There are 40 different combinations of dt_from and dt_to. You are telling SQL to treat each of these combinations as something unique to display.

Comment: The flip side is that without the group by, you get one row because it says to find the minimum dt_from and the maximum dt_to and just combine them. And so you get one row. The GroupBy means you get one row for every unique combination of dt_from and dt_to.

Comment: @pmbAustin, good point. Wouldn't that mean that in the grouped query, the min and max are essentially useless?

Comment: Well, it's not possible to tell that unless given the data. There could be many rows with the same dt_from and dt_to combination, in that case, the MIN and MAX will pick the appropriate values from each sub-group, and are definitely not useless. There's nothing to indicate that dt_from + dt_to is unique in the table.